# Change caption prefix for new environment declared to Endfloat

Tags: endfloat

I have both figures and tables in a latex doc. I'm wrapping an environment around `figure` to ensure that all tables and figures are processed in order, which solves the ordering issue. However, the marker in the text still shows `table` for the figure wrapper, as it's been defined as a `table` type.

How can I change the caption prefix for the new environment so that it's still declared as a `table` type, yet has the prefix `Figure`?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newenvironment{fakefigure}
  {\begin{figure}}
  {\end{figure}}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{fakefigure}{table}

\begin{document}

\section{Data}

\begin{table}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\begin{fakefigure}
\centering
\includegraphics{histoOne1}
\caption{My caption for this figure}
\label{fig:MyFigure1}
\end{fakefigure}

\begin{table}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```